# What does it mean for a window to be the active OpenGL window in SDL2?

Tags: c, opengl, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to understand the concept of a window being the active OpenGL window in SDL 2.0. The documentation says that SDL_GL_GetCurrentWindow() returns the currently active OpenGL window. My understanding is that I can have multiple OpenGL contexts, one of which is active for a given window. To switch the active context I would use SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(). But how do I switch the active window? Does SDL_GL_MakeCurrent() switch both the context and the window?

Comment: `SDL_GL_MakeCurrent()` also sets the active window. It should do so because it has `window` argument. The real question is what it will do if context passed is not associated with passed window.